# Is there a way to change color of an already made object?

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a program in processing, and want to change the color (fill) of an object I've already made. I used the fill(0,0,0) command to change the color to black, but I want a way to change the color of it to 255,0,0 (red). Is there a way to change it, or do I just have to make a new ellipse above it?

I've tried making a variable inside the first fill "fill(test,0,0) where I changed the value of "test" from 0 to 255, didn't work

```
void draw() {
  fill(0,0,0);
  ellipse(490, 140, 100, 100);
  ellipse(490, 400, 100, 100);
  if (mousePressed == true && mouseY >= 90 && mouseY <= 190 && mouseX >= 440 && mouseX <= 540) {
      fill(255,0,0);
      ellipse(490, 140, 100, 100);
}
}
```

I expected for the first ellipse to change colors due to me changing the value of the first made fill that was used to color the first ellipse in

Comment: You're not changing the ellipse's color, you're drawing a new ellipse over the first one (with a different color). This should visually be the same, so I'm wondering if you're sure that your code enters the if condition. Try adding this inside the if: `println("I'm inside the if");` or something like that, and verify if you can successfully trigger your condition. Also, note that this condition will be checked about 60 times per second, so it may be just a blink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `if-else` for choosing the color, like:

```java
void draw() {
    fill(0,0,0);
    if (mousePressed == true && mouseY >= 90 && mouseY <= 190 && mouseX >= 440 && mouseX <= 540) {
        fill(255,0,0);
        ellipse(490, 140, 100, 100);
        fill(0,0,0);
    } else {
        ellipse(490, 140, 100, 100);
    }

    ellipse(490, 400, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit misleading, I don't actually think it matters if you can change the color or make a new object on top of the old one. Either way, thanks